# QGIS 2.2 Raster Merge losing color data

Tags: qgis, merge, raster-conversion

I'm trying to merge a couple of GeoTiff maps using Raster > Miscellaneous > Merge but the merge is only coming out in grayscale. The geotifs are using palettes color. How do I get the merge to keep the color information?

Answer (score 3):

You have to expand the GeoTiffs to RGBA. Each of your GeoTiffs has a different palette, and GDAL (working in the background of QGIS) can not merge and repalette in one step.

Try `Raster -> Convert -> PCT to RGB` or `gdal_translate -expand RGBA`.

Comment: Thanks, I thought I had tried this last night and it didn't work. I was mistaken in my frustration. Thanks for the help.